# My app is not running on OS version greater than Marshmallow

Tags: java, android

I developed zipper lock screen app. The app works lower than android version 6.0 but not work upper than 6.0.. but I want the app work in all the android version.. is it possible if yes, then how?
plzzzzzz help me..

I have posted my codes of menifest and gradle.build app files.
if you need the codes of any file then tell me.
I will post the codes there.
thank you much in advance..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.valentines.zipperlock">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PHONE_STATE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name="com.valentines.zipperlock.SettingActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.valentines.zipperlock.LockscreenActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <service android:name="com.valentines.zipperlock.service.LockscreenService" />
        <service android:name="com.valentines.zipperlock.service.LockscreenViewService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.valentines.zipperlock.Developerintro"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_developerintro"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName="com.valentines.zipperlock.SettingActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.valentines.zipperlock.SettingActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.valentines.zipperlock.Splash"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>



apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.valentines.zipperlock"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
}
```

Comment: "but not work upper than 6.0" - what specifically happens? Will it not install, or crash on start or some action, or something else? Is there anything in the `adb logcat` ?

Comment: it does not show any error

Answer (score -1):

You have to upgrade your compileSdkVersion.With compileSdkVersion 22 you can run the app on a API 22 device. And API 22 corresponds to Android 5.1.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. But you should get better hints whats going wrong. Have a look at compiler errors/warnings, Lint warnings and so on.

Comment: _"With compileSdkVersion 22 you can run the app on a API 22 device."_ That's not what it means. The `compileSdkVersion` determines which APIs will be available to you _at compile-time_.

Comment: CompileSdkVersion 22 means that the APIs until the 22 are the only APIs that are available to you at compile time. So, maybe it does not fix all the problems but it has to be done at least.

Answer (score -1):

*Update your **gradle** file*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.valentines.zipperlock"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
}
```

*For more details on sdk version, check these:*

- [Official doc on build numbers](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers)
- [How to pick compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, and targetSdkVersion](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd)

Comment: build tool started downloading after putting these codes in gradle file..

Comment: @TariqAziz Yeah, it's alright. Android Studio is downloading the higher sdk versions so that your app can support higher versions as well

Comment: @Mohammad_Zain_Abbas .. ok. wait.. I tell u after completing this process.

Comment: @TariqAziz Okay sure :)

Comment: its done successfully. but after this, the app did not run in marshmallow 6.0

Comment: You have to update your code as well. Some libraries only work on higher sdk versions and some work for old sdk versions.

Comment: You have not done it correctly, that's why it doesn't run on marshmallow 6.0

Comment: can you give me your whatsapp or fb id?

Comment: You can contact me on chat here on stackoverflow